# Python, checksum of a dict

Tags: python, checksum

I'm thinking to create a checksum of a dict to know if it was modified or not
For the moment i have that:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> import pickle
>>> d = {'k': 'v', 'k2': 'v2'}
>>> z = pickle.dumps(d)
>>> hashlib.md5(z).hexdigest()
'8521955ed8c63c554744058c9888dc30'
```

Perhaps a better solution exists?

*Note: I want to create an unique id of a dict to create a good Etag.*

**EDIT:** I can have abstract data in the dict.

Comment: What does your dict contain? If it's just strings (say) you could just hash the sorted string representation: `hash(repr(sorted(my_dict.items())))`.

Comment: What's abstract data? The stability and working-ness of the dict-hash algorithm depends strongly on what data it holds. For instance, what if you have a dict of dicts?

Comment: these data type: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this:

```
reduce(lambda x,y : x^y, [hash(item) for item in d.items()])
```

Take the hash of each (key, value) tuple in the dict and XOR them alltogether.

@katrielalex
If the dict contains unhashable items you could do this:

```
hash(str(d))
```

or maybe even better

```
hash(repr(d))
```

Comment: What if the dict contains unhashable items?

Comment: You can't do `str(d)` without false negatives, because the order in which the items appear in the string representation is undefined.

Comment: I ran a test with adding 1000000 key/value pairs to two dictionaries, but in different order and it didn't cause a false negative (str(d1) == str(d2) was always True). I think you're right, but changes are very small. This might be enough for caching. Would using repr(d) give a defined order? I thought repr() depends on the internal order of the dict as well.

Comment: There is no way to get items in defined order out of a dict without doing `sorted(d.iteritems())`

Comment: @agf: Your definitely right! But the first solution (the `reduce()` thing) combines the hashes with XORs, which discards the order of the elements.

Answer (score 8):

In Python 3, the hash function is initialized with a random number, which is different for each python session. If that is not acceptable for the intended application, use e.g. zlib.adler32 to build the checksum for a dict:

```
import zlib

d={'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}
checksum=0
for item in d.items():
    c1 = 1
    for t in item:
        c1 = zlib.adler32(bytes(repr(t),'utf-8'), c1)
    checksum=checksum ^ c1

print(checksum)
```

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend an approach very similar to the one your propose, but with some extra guarantees:

```
import hashlib, json
hashlib.md5(json.dumps(d, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=True).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

- `sort_keys=True`: keep the same hash if the order of your keys changes
- `ensure_ascii=True`: in case you have some non-ascii characters, to make sure the representation does not change

We use this for our ETag.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether `pickle` guarantees you that the hash is serialized the same way every time.

If you only have dictionaries, I would go for o combination of calls to `keys()`, `sorted()`, build a string based on the sorted key/value pairs and compute the checksum on that

Comment: `"".join("%s,%s"%(x,y) for x, y in sorted(foo.iteritems()))` (where foo is the dict) might work as a signature which you can hash.

Comment: And what about if i have abstract data in my dict? that's not a problem?

Comment: i think then you'd have to do a recursive function that would serialize the sorted data for each sub structure

Comment: What if the dict contains dicts? Then string-formatting them doesn't give a reliably-unique result.

Comment: that is why I said the recursive function is needed - each dict contained in the main one should be treated like the main one - its keys sorted and serialized based on that

Answer (score 1):

I think you may not realise some of the subtleties that go into this. The first problem is that the order that items appear in a dict is not defined by the implementation. This means that simply asking for `str` of a dict doesn't work, because you could have

```
str(d1) == "{'a':1, 'b':2}"
str(d2) == "{'b':2, 'a':1}"
```

and these will hash to different values. If you have only hashable items in the dict, you can hash them and then join up their hashes, as [@Bart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923780/python-checksum-of-a-dict/6923909#6923909) does or simply

```
hash(tuple(sorted(hash(x) for x in d.items())))
```

Note the `sorted`, because you have to ensure that the hashed tuple comes out in the same order irrespective of which order the items appear in the dict. If you have dicts in the dict, you could recurse this, but it will be complicated.

BUT it would be easy to break any implementation like this if you allow *arbitrary* data in the dictionary, since you can simply write an object with a broken `__hash__` implementation and use that. And you can't use `id`, because then you might have equal items which compare different.

The moral of the story is that hashing dicts isn't supported in Python for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you wanted to generate an Etag based on the dictionary content, [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) which preserves the order of the dictionary may be better candidate here. Just iterator through the key,value pairs and construct your Etag string.