# Comparing 2 model entities

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there an easy way to compare to entities to to check for property value differences? I want something like this:

```
me = User.get_by_id( 28 )
cloned_me = me

cloned_me.first_name = 'Tom'

if me != cloned_me:
    self.response.out.write( 'These 2 objects have different property values' )
```

Comment: `cloned_me` isn't a copy here - it's simply another reference to the same object. This check will always return `True`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elegant way to avoid .put() on unchanged entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330974/elegant-way-to-avoid-put-on-unchanged-entities)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplest scenario you can compare objects field by field e.g.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def compare(user1, user2):
    for field in user1._meta.fields: 
        val1 = getattr(user1, field.name)
        val2 = getattr(user2, field.name)
        if val1 != val2:
            print "%s differ '%s' != '%s'"%(field.name, val1, val2)
            break

compare(User(username="anurag"), User(username="uniyal"))
```

output:

```
username differ 'anurag' != 'uniyal'
```

You can later on improve it if you need to further compare foerign keys etc

and i think you are aware that in your example `clone_me` is not actually a clone of `me`, it is `me`

Comment: So to make a clone I would use copy.copy?

Comment: for cloning see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733609/how-do-i-clone-a-django-model-instance-object-and-save-it-to-the-database

Answer (score 0):

Try using sets:

```
differences = set(me.__dict__) ^ set(cloned_me.__dict__)
if differences:
    self.response.out.write('These 2 objects have different property values')
```

You could even output the attributes that were different (they're contained in the new differences set).

Comment: Is this an efficient method of comparing? From my understanding, bitwise comparisons are expensive.

Comment: I'm not sure how expensive it is. The time difference between this and  anything possibly faster is probably negligible unless you have a very large data set.